# Disable CMS feature based on role Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, user-rights, users

Is it possible to disable text color pick, or bold text in richt text box for specific user group?
My client doesn't want that an specific role group do changes on text designs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable/disable the feature from RTF field [click here](http://blog.guusbeltman.nl/post/2018/01/18/handling-rich-text-content-fields-in-sdl-tridion-cms), but I dont think we can do this for specific user group(s) definitely something not out of the box.

Comment: I agree with Hem on this. If you need to control it per user group then it would need to be a GUI Extension.